# Find Orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$$U = Sp\{(3, 3, 1)\}$$

How can I find the Orthogonal complement ?
I'm not sure how to calculate it.

In the book I'm learning from it's saying that I need to write the vectors of $U$ in $Ax = 0$ where the lines of $A$ are the vectors of $U$.

But since $U$ has only one vector I'm not sure how could this help me to find the orthogonal complement

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am trying to find the orthogonal complement of $U$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I wrote in the post. $U=Sp\{(3,3,1)\}$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess $U$ is the vector space spanned by the vector $(3,3,1)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde oh i'm sorry I thought it's accepted to write a span this way.

Comment: @thanasissdr Yes that's exactly what I ment

Comment: We usually use the notation $U = \langle (3,3,1) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane of equation $P \equiv 3x+3y+1z=0$.

It has dimension equal to $2$ and every vector $u=(x,y,z) \in P$ is such that $\langle u, v\rangle=0$ where $v=(3,3,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $U$ has only one dimension, it is indeed true that $A$ will have only one line. Hence, the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ is the set of vectors $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that
\begin{equation}
3x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0
\end{equation}
Setting respectively $x_3 = 0$ and $x_1 = 0$, you can find 2 independent vectors in $U^\perp$, for example $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,-1,3)$. These generate $U^\perp$ since it is two dimensional (being the orthogonal complement of a one dimensional subspace in three dimensions). Hence, we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
U^\perp = \operatorname{Span}\{(1,-1,0),(0,-1,3)\}.
\end{equation}
Note that there would be many (infinitely many) other ways to describe $U^\perp$.

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary answer to the previous ones, we have that the orthogonal complement of $U$ is the set 
$V=U^\perp = \left\{ \vec{\mathbf v} = \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z  \end{pmatrix}: x,y,z \in \mathbb R\right\},$ such that:
$$\vec{\mathbf u}\cdot \vec{\mathbf v} = 0, \quad{\text{ for every $\mathbf{\vec u}\in U$ }} .$$

Any vector $ \vec {\mathbf{u}} \in U$ will be of the form $a\cdot (3,3,1)=(3a,3a,a)$, where $a$ is a scalar in $\mathbb R$.

Having said that, we have:
$$\begin{array}[t]{l} (3a, 3a, a) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z \end{pmatrix}= 0\\
3ax + 3ay + az = 0\\
3x + 3y + z = 0, \quad {\text{ since we want the above equation to hold for every $a\neq 0$.}} 
\end{array}$$

That means $V = U^\perp =\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\z \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb R^3: 3x+3y+z = 0\right\}$.

Any extra information is included in other answers.